# Rejecting MDM push dictionary because it does not have the right magic string

Tags: mdm

I use the apple's mdm and find a strange problem.
This iphone device could have been mdm control, it works fine,but suddenly lost control, see xcode the device log appears, "Rejecting MDM Push dictionary because it does not have the right magic string."
Is this how to solve this?

```html
Aug 1 08:03:04 iPhone6 apsd(PersistentConnection)[93] <Notice>: 2017-08-01 08:03:04 +0800 apsd[93]: <APSCourier: 0x155d12f70>: Received message for enabled topic 'com.apple.mgmt.External.69e3a6a4-4f53' with payload '{
aps = {
};
mdm = "5E73DE3E-ADE2-4955-B58C";
}' onInterface: WWAN for device token: YES with priority (null)
Aug 1 08:03:04 iPhone6 mdmd(libdispatch.dylib)[4508] <Notice>: Push token received.
Aug 1 08:03:04 iPhone6 mdmd(ApplePushService)[4508] <Notice>: Received push notification.
Aug 1 08:03:04 iPhone6 mdmd(ApplePushService)[4508] <Notice>: Rejecting MDM push dictionary because it does not have the right magic string.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your push magic doesn't seem to be correct it should almost always be in `UUID` format, double check that you are sending the correct one, or show the code how you're sending it/obtaining it

SOURCE:

https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf

> `The PushMagic token is a hexadecimal string, likely a simple random
>   UUID (in UUID format).`